How to programatically interact with a take button on a website using autohotkey script
I have a website that shows a take button whenever I load it. I want to write an autohotkey script that automatically clicks the take button immediatelly after I load the page.
I tried to write an autohotkey script that could interact with the take button's element ID but it did not work. I was expecting the autohotkey script to click the take button whenever I loaded the page but that did not work out.

Tried imagesearch yet?

When you say "I tried to write an autohotkey script that could interact with the take button's element ID" how did you go about this? In any case, a comprehensive solution for browser automation tasks in AutoHotkey is Descolada's UIautomation but it has a learning curve. There is a much simpler solution that could work just as well, but it depends on your browser and your web page. What browser are you using?

Hello, thank you for your feedback. I am using google chrome.

I need to automatically click a button with an element I'd "sos_btn" whenever I load the webpage. Could you kindly help me achieve this?
